# To accept -d @json , How put method should be written in rest api

Tags: java, rest

In PUT rest call , Using curl I would like to use -d option , what should be method signature . I am using java.

```
 curl -X PUT -u testUser 'http://hostname:port/method' -d @test.json  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This should be my curl when I fire .

I have written a method signature which accepts string as input

```
@PUT @Path ("/test")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response method(String input) throws Exception {...}
```

When I run above command , Having above method signature is throwing error .

```
 Error processing command: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

String input needs data in json format .

```
 {
    "name" : "test",
    "host" : "10.xx.xx.xx",
    "port" : 22
      .
      .
 } //around 15 values
```

having these in a single url like this

```
 "http://hostname:port/method?name=test&host=10.xx.xx.xx&port=22........."
```

makes url grow pretty long but its working though.

I would like to use -d option to send json input through a file.

What should be the method signature for curl to work with -d @test.json  in java ?

--Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We cannot help you without the details about that Exception. Post the stack trace.

Comment: No other stacktrace is displaying , It is just that exception . 
By the way , Is that method signature holds good for sending data through -d ??

Comment: If I change method signature to - public Response method(JSONObject inputJson) it is taking JsonInput